# manage the union of two code class with manytomany in springboot

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, spring-boot

In my SpringBoot + Angular project I have to manage the union between two `Code`. For example I have to manage that when I have the `A1` `code`, I have a select where I can choose `a1`, `a2` and `a3` `code`. How can I join the two Code. I thought a `@ManyToMany` value in `AssociationA` class. Is that correct?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "codeA")
public class CodeA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String code;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "codeB")
public class CodeB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String code;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "associationA")
public class AssociationA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CodeA codeId;
    
    @Column
    private double price;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "associationB")
public class AssociationB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CodeB codeId;
    
    @Column
    private double price;
}
```

I leave the link to the stackblitz for managing the classes in the `ts`. and how I thought about `html` : [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmavig?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please post your code here instead of linking to it. Also, this part: 'I have to manage that when I have the A1 code, I have a select where I can choose a1, a2 and a3 code' is not really clear, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @crizzis I posted the `ts` part of the code on stackblitz because otherwise there was too much code in the question and I couldn't post it. As for the `code`, I tried to explain it in the html on stack. I need to connect the two classes and I was trying to figure out how